# Amazon app store Multiple APK Support like Android market?

Tags: android, apk, amazon-appstore

Does Amazon app store support multiple APK uploading like Android market?

Answer (score 1):

The Amazon Appstore does support multiple APKs for the one app. This is confirmed in the [Amazon documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/fire-tv/docs/using-device-targeting). It is possible to upload multiple APKs for different platforms and capabilities including screen size and density, OpenGL compression format, architecture or API version.

Multiple APK support in the Amazon Appstore works the same as the [multiple APK support in the Play Store](http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html), where the app android:versionCode must be unique for each uploaded APK.

You can use the gradle build script to [automate the generation of unique versionCode for the multiple APKs](https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/06/30/android-ndk-version-code-scheme-for-publishing-apks-per-architecture/). Here is an example that generates different APKs based on device architecture:

```
   splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk true
        }
    }

    project.ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi': 1, 'armeabi-v7a': 2, 'arm64-v8a': 3, 'mips': 5, 'mips64': 6, 'x86': 8, 'x86_64': 9]

    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(
                    com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI), 0) * 10000000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've attempted to submit an apk for API 14+ and another for API 21+. Amazon rejects the apk for 21+ as the devices are already targeted by a different APK. The documentation can say what it wants, but shipping two apks for the same device vector (All other Android devices is a single device).

Answer (score 0):

You can visit developer.amazon.com. Create an account there and  your are free to upload android apps. They also give you an option to choose when do you want the app to be available for the users. Unlike android market, the app will not be live immediately. It will undergo a review process and only after approval it will become live. You cannot edit the apk details once it is sent for review.

Comment: Thanks for respone but the question is is possible to upload  in Amazonr different APKs for my application that are each targeted to different device configurations?

Comment: Yes but make sure they do not have the same package.

Comment: Guys, the question is another one. I've got my application and two apks of that: one for tablet and another one phones.In Android market I can publish this two apks as a single application(from the user's point of view), this feature is known as Multiple APK support. I wonder if there is such functionality in Amazone app store

Comment: If your app is universal then you do not need to have two separate APKs. If you have used things like fragments which support only tablet 3.0, then you have a point in creating different APK. If your using phone UI, then just put all your layouts in layout-xlarge.Just try uploading and see what response you get. With such little information, I cant guide you much...Try uploading first and see if it accepts or not. It will tell you what error your are getting

Comment: layout-xlarge is unspported on android 2.2. Thats why I have two applications....

Answer (score 0):

This feature is unsupported by Amazon Market

http://www.amazonappstoredev.com/2011/02/when-to-create-multiple-binaries-for-your-app.html

Comment: 5yrs on as you'd expect this answer is out of date and wrong. Currently  the Amazon app store supports multiple .apks